# Unsecured & secured HTTP

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, https

I have an application which uses 2 web sites (so I guess that is 2 applications...).  The user logs on via a https website and is then diverted to a unsecure http website application on successful logon (using forms authentication).  I (and others) have started getting the message

"The current web page is trying to open a site in your Trusted sites list. Do you want to allow this?"

when the user is redirected.

Is there a way to stop this in the server configuration or in the code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the user is accountable for any actions performed on the "unsecured site", it should not be unsecured. It's not safe to authenticate a user on HTTPS, then let them perform actions using that authentication over HTTP.

If someone is not worried about a man-in-the-middle, it doesn't make sense for them to use HTTPS at all. On the other hand, if a man-in-the-middle attack is a possibility (and in general I assume it is) then sending the session identifier cookie (or other credential) obtained via secure login over an insecure channel allows an attacker to steal it and forge requests to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing at login is to post the login information from the secured page to the non-secured page, which in turn pops up that message.

What you could have done is for the secured login to post to a secured page, then redirect from there to the non-secured page. That should remove the message.

Answer (score 0):

That message appears to be IE's trusted sites warning. There is no way to control it from a remote server, nor should there be as it would be a security risk.